# Attempted to call an undefined method named "Create" of class "Symfony\Component\HttpClient\CurlHttpClient"

Tags: php, symfony4

I need to use basic token auth to API, and I want to create service to do that (I'll be using these features in other controllers), so I created service called `smsapi`

**SMSApiService.php**

```php
<?php

namespace App\Service;

use Symfony\Contracts\HttpClient\HttpClientInterface;

class SMSApiService
{
    private $httpClient;
    private $apiHost;
    private $apiToken;

    public function __construct(HttpClientInterface $httpClient, $apiToken, $apiHost)
    {
        $this->apiHost = $apiHost;
        $this->apiToken = $apiToken;
        $this->httpClient = $httpClient::Create([    
    'auth_bearer' => $this->apiToken]);
    }

    public function sendSMS()
    {
        $response = $this->httpClient->request('GET', $this->apiHost);
        $statusCode = $response->getContent();
        return $statusCode;
    }
}
```

Due to symfony docs:
https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/http_client.html#authentication

I always get the error:

```
Attempted to call an undefined method named "Create" of class "Symfony\Component\HttpClient\CurlHttpClient".
```

What should I do, to use create method and enter API credentials? (API token). `apiHost` and `apiToken` are provided by `services.yaml`.

Comment: You already have an instance of HttpClientInterface being passed into the constructor, why are you trying to build another one?

Comment: The error occurs because you call a **static method from an instance of object** ($httpClient::Create). A [static method is called from a classname](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php) like this : HttpClient::Create. But as Jonnix noticed, you already have an instance passed in your constructor...

Comment: Sorry guys, but im totally newbie. Tried:    public function __construct($apiToken, $apiHost)
    {
        $this->httpClient = HttpClientInterface::create();
    } give me the same result...     public function __construct(HttpClientInterface $httpClient, $apiToken, $apiHost)
    {
        $apiClient = $this->httpClient::create();
    } gives me :Class name must be a valid object or a string: thanks for your patience!